# Django forms read a dynamic form ChoiceField value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form set up with a dynamic ChoiceField with values pulled from the database. The form takes information from athletes registering for an athletic competition and sorts them by weight class. I have made the form to display the entries as needed and I'm able to read the ChoiceField, however I can't seem to read the **value** of the RadioButton that the user has selected. The code to display the dynamic form is:

```
def __init__(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    weight_groups = ClassGroup.objects.all()
    weight_classes = RegistrationClassOrder.objects.filter(event = event).order_by('class_order')

    for single_class in weight_classes.all():
        self.fields['%s' % single_class.competition_class.class_group.group_name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[ (o.id, o.class_name) for o in weight_class.competition_class.class_group.classes_in_group.all()], widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label=weight_class.competition_class.class_group.group_name, required=False)
```

This renders the form as:

- Junior Men

  - Junior Men's Lightweight
  - Junior Men's Middleweight
  - Junior Men's Heavyweight
- Junior Women

  - Junior Women's Lightweight
  - Junior Women's Middleweight
  - Junior Women's Heavyweight

in HTML:

```
<th>
  <label for="id_Junior Men_0">Junior Men</label>
</th>
<td><ul>
  <li><label for="id_Junior Men_0"><input id="id_Junior Men_0" name="Junior Men" type="radio" value="97" /> Junior Men's Lightweight</label></li>
  <li><label for="id_Junior Men_1"><input id="id_Junior Men_1" name="Junior Men" type="radio" value="98" /> Junior Men's Middleweight</label></li>
  <li><label for="id_Junior Men_2"><input id="id_Junior Men_2" name="Junior Men" type="radio" value="99" /> Junior Men's Heavyweight</label></li>
</ul></td>
```

In the view to process the form I use the following code:

```
for field in form.fields:
    if WeightClassGroup.objects.filter(group_name=field).count() > 0: #checking to see if the field's name matches a weight class in the database

        newentry = Entry(
            athlete = athlete,
            event = event,
            athlete_class = Classes.objects.get(id=field)
            )
```

The 'field' variable in the above code block refers to the *label* of the ChoiceField, but how do I get the *value* of the option that the user has selected? In the POSTBACK data for the form each ChoiceField is shown as something like **'Junior Men: 97'** where 97 is the id of the weight class that the user selected on the form. The 'field' variable returns the unicode string 'Junior Men', however I just want the number. It was my belief that choices are stored as a dict, however that doesn't seem to work, as I can't access the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form.cleaned_data` rather than `form.fields` for the submitted data. I'm assuming you are validating the form - `form.is_valid()` before using the data.

With this your view will be like:

```
for fname, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
    if WeightClassGroup.objects.filter(group_name=fname).count() > 0: #checking to see if the field's name matches a weight class in the database

        newentry = Entry(
            athlete = athlete,
            event = event,
            athlete_class = Classes.objects.get(id=value) #use value for id in submitted data
            )
```